# Viewing the exact HTTP Request/Response communication of a JAX-RS client

Tags: java, jax-rs, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to figure out how to debug my tests by viewing the HTTP my client is sending

```
testPutActivitity(com.lm.controller.JaxRSActivatorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.521 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<404> but was:<200>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:542)
    at com.lm.controller.JaxRSActivatorTest.testPutActivitity(JaxRSActivatorTest.java:44)
```

With the new undertow server, some things seem to have changed, so the documentation I'm finding no longer seems to be relevant.

What I'd like to know is how I can view the HTTP Request/Response transmitted from the client? (if it matters I should be using the RESTEasy client)

```
package com.lm.controller;

import com.lm.test.RESTCtrlTestBase;
import static com.lm.test.TestUtil.testWar;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Filters;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RootTest extends RESTCtrlTestBase {

    public RootTest() {
    }

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    @Deployment( testable = false )
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        WebArchive ar = testWar()
                .addPackages(
                        false,
                        Filters.exclude( ".*Test.*" ),
                        "com.lm.controller",
                        "com.lm.activity"
                );
        // System.out.println( "ar = " + ar.toString( true ) );
        return ar;
    }

    @Test
    public void getRoot() {
        WebTarget target = client.target( deploymentURI );
        log.debug( "targetURI = {}", target.getUri() );
        Response res = target.request().get();
        assertEquals( 200, res.getStatus() );
    }
}
```

I've tried writing an [interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028915/206466) but it doesn't output the request/response exactly as it is transmitted, also it only seems to get loaded for the server but not the test client above.

Comment: until such time as this is not painful I'm using wireshark to watch localhost traffic to and from port 8080

Comment: did you find any way to solve your problem?

Comment: no I have not, the developers of these libraries did not make this easy.